# Negate a -switch (all but the switch parameter)

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

How to obtain all the items except the one indicated by a switch?

I use:

```
Get-Disk -UniqueId 4875E7EB064AA60
```

to get information only a specific disk drive.

I want to use the same command, but get all drives except this one.

Something like this (in pseudo code):

```
Get-Disk -not( -UniqueId 4875E7EB064AA60 )
```

Comment: `Get-Disk | Where-Object UniqueId -ne 4875E7EB064AA60`

Comment: Thanks Ansgar and Don... your answers work fine... but my question goes also in the direction of language capabilities and  flexibility... if there were a ( -not( ??? ) ) parameter would be great also for several other commands/situations...

Comment: No. The language doesn't provide a general means to "invert" a parameter value. Some cmdlets have parameters allowing for negative selections (like `Get-ChildItem -Exclude`, `SelectString -NotMatch`, ...), but that's about it.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell as a language does not allow for "inverting" a parameter value. You need to filter the returned results with `Where-Object` after the fact.

```
Get-Disk | Where-Object { $_.UniqueId -ne '4875E7EB064AA60' }
```

There are several cmdlets that do allow expressing "everything but this" semantics, but it's up to the individual cmdlet if and how they implement that. For example:

- The `Get-ChildItem` and `Select-Object` cmdlets have a parameter `-Exclude` that allows to exclude particular results.
- The `Select-String` cmdlet has a switch `-NotMatch` to invert what is selected by the parameter `-Pattern`.
- All cmdlets with filter parameters that allow expressing a `not` condition (like `Get-WmiObject -Filter`, `Get-ADUser -Filter`, or `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter`) obviously also allow expressing a "not this" semantic.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that, even if PowerShell did implement a `-not` switch as a common parameter (i.e. syntax), individual cmdlets would still need to do some work to make it actually take effect (i.e. semantics). In fact, it might not make sense for every switch to be inverted, so even the syntax could not be implemented at the language level, without taking more information from parameter bindings. (What would `Set-Location -not -Path C:\Users` mean?)